# Decent file format for my map saves

Tags: .net, serialization

I'm creating a map editor for a XNA game that I'm working on.

Basically, all the editor needs to really save is the X of the tile, the Y of the tile, the Z of the tile, a value called TX and a value called TY associated with the tile. This totals out for just 5 values per tile (there will be about 20000 tiles per map). I was going to save the file simply as bytes but the bytes can only go to 256 and isn't enough to cover some (most really) of the tiles.

Is there some kind of save format already out there that will allow me to save these 5 (possibly more later) values easily and read them back with ease?  I'm doing this all in VB.net so I would appreciate it anything you provided me was at least .net (I'm fine with anything .net, I can convert and, in fact, my project is actually both C#.net and VB.net so I shouldn't have any problems with that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is protobuf format. It is pure binary, portable, fast and supports versioning out of the box. Generally looks like a good choice for your purposes.

Comparing to XML you would probably get much smaller files and faster map loading.

There is a nice library for .NET:
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Answer (score 2):

look at http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

i'm using this in something that I did and it's very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I save my maps in XML, the files might get big (which can be overcome with a compression wrapper), but will not only be human readable/editable, it's also easy to write different tools in different languages, as most support some form of XML editing or even XML to object mapping.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are essentially storing a table of "rows" with identical format, how about a simple [comma-separated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file?

Not as space-efficient as "real" binary but not as wasteful as XML either. Fairly easy to add new "columns" and generally easy to work with.